# Synchronize slicer issue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a hierarchy sllicer

I have an issue when sychronizing slicer when selecting all

I use the synchronization option in powerbi in order to synchronize page 1 and page 2.

When I select one item it works but when I choose select all it doesn't work, there is no synchronization between the two pages in the report that I attached.

I put a pbix file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1snmzHqquslCUZmvC5AMPzMLQ1WFY0O6A/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Create public link in google drive.

Comment: @mkRabbani, done. Please check from your side.

Comment: This is really strange :( and seems like a Power BI Bug!. You can report a Bug explaining the issue.